# Sufficiency of Lebesgue's Criterion for Riemann Integrability

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

In my notes there is a proof of the the following:

**Proposition.** A function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if $f$ is bounded and

$$\text{disc}(f):=\{x\in [a,b] : f \text{ is discontinuous at } x \}$$

has measure zero.

However, am having trouble with some parts of the proof which I have highlighted in bold:

**Proof.** Suppose $f$ is bounded and $\text{disc}(f)$ has measure zero. Let $M=\sup_{[a,b]}|f|$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By definition of measure zero, there exist $(a_j,b_j)$, $j\geq 1$, such that $\text{disc}(f)\subset \bigcup_{j\geq 1} (a_j,b_j)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(b_j-a_j)<\epsilon$. Define

$$A:=\bigcup_{j\geq 1} (a_j,b_j) \hspace{1cm} K:=[a,b]\setminus A$$

Note that $K$ is closed and bounded, hence compact. Also, continuity implies that, for each $x\in K$, there exist $\delta(x)=\boldsymbol{\delta(x,\epsilon)\in (0,\epsilon)}$ such that

$$ y\in[a,b], |x-y|\leq\delta(x) \implies |f(x)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon \hspace{0.5cm}(*)$$

The collection of open intervals $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x))$, $x\in K$, covers $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there exist finitely many elements of $K$, say $k_1,\dots,k_r\in K$, such that

$$K\subset \bigcup_{s=1}^r (k_s-\delta_s,k_s+\delta_s)$$ where $\delta_s:=\delta(k_s)$. Let $L$ be the set of all points of the form $k_s\pm \delta_s$ and consider the partition

$$P:=\{a,b\}\cup\{x\in L:a\leq x\leq b\}$$

of $[a,b]$. Let $\mathcal{I}(P)=\{I_1,\dots,I_n\}$ be the compact intervals determined by this partition. For $I_j\in \mathcal{I}(P)$ we distinguish between two cases:

**Case 1.** There exist $1\leq s\leq r$ such that $I_j\subset[k_s-\delta_s,k_s+\delta_s]$. We call $\mathcal{J}_{good}$ the set all such $j$. For $j\in\mathcal{J}_{good}$ we have, using $(*)$ above,

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(k_s)|+|f(k_s)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon+\epsilon=2\epsilon$$

for all $x,y\in I_j$. Hence $\text{osc}_f (I_j):=\sup_{x,y\in I_j}|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2\epsilon$.

**Case 2.** There is no $1\leq s\leq r$ such that $I_j\subset[k_s-\delta_s,k_s+\delta_s]$. We call $\mathcal{J}_{bad}$ the set all such $j$. For $j\in\mathcal{J}_{bad}$ we have $\text{osc}_f (I_j)\leq 2M$. We claim that

$$\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}_{bad}} |I_j|\leq 3\epsilon$$

Let $I_j=[x_{j-1},x_j]$. If $x_{j-1}=a$ or $x_{j}=b$ we have the bound $\boldsymbol{|I_j|\leq\epsilon}$. Hence we only have to show that

$$\sum\limits_{\substack{j\in\mathcal{J}_{bad} \\ a,b\notin I_j}} |I_j|\leq \epsilon \hspace{0.5cm} (**)$$

We know that in this case $x_{j-1},x_j \in L$. But then the only way that we can have $I_j\not\subset[k_s-\delta_s,k_s+\delta_s]$ for some $s$ is to have

$$I_j\subset [a,b]\setminus \bigcup_{s=1}^r (k_s-\delta_s,k_s+\delta_s)$$

and since $K\subset \bigcup_{s=1}^r (k_s-\delta_s,k_s+\delta_s)$ we find that

$$I_j\subset[a,b]\setminus K\subset A=\bigcup_{j\geq 1} (a_j,b_j) $$

Hence $$\bigcup\limits_{\substack{j\in\mathcal{J}_{bad} \\ a,b\notin I_j}}\subset \bigcup_{j\geq 1} (a_j,b_j) $$

Because the intervals $I_j$ have disjoints interiors, **$(**)$ now follows from $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(b_j-a_j)<\epsilon$**.

The proof then concludes using Darboux's criterion.

As you can see I have three issues:

1. Why do we need $\delta(x)<\epsilon$?
2. Why is the bound $|I_j|\leq \epsilon$ valid if $j\in\mathcal{J}_{bad}$ and $x_{j-1}=a$ or $x_j=b$?
3. Why does $\sum\limits_{\substack{j\in\mathcal{J}_{bad} \\ a,b\notin I_j}} |I_j|\leq \epsilon $ follows from $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(b_j-a_j)<\epsilon$?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Your proof is about necessity of the Lebesgue's criterion. Am looking at sufficiency.

Comment: You are right. Here is a proof of sufficiency of Lebesgue's theorem based on the idea of modulus of continuity. This concept is discuss in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis book and in Billingsley's Convergence in Probability monograph.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think this is a trick that is used in this proof ( just like $\epsilon 2^{-n}$ trick used in a lot of measure-theoretic results).
2. Suppose $x_{j-1} =a$. Clearly $a \notin L$ so $x_j$ must be either $k_s+\delta_s$ or $k_s-\delta_s $ for some $1\leq s\leq r$ (Because the endpoints of $I_js$ are formed by the points in $P$). In either case, there exists $k_{s'} \in K$ such that $|I_j| \leq |(a+\delta_{s'})-a|$, where $s'\leq r$. By the choice of $\delta_{s'} (=\delta(k_{s'}))\,$, $|I_j| \leq \epsilon$.
3. $I_js $ have disjoint interiors. So the result follows from the countable-additivity, sub-additivity & the monotonicity of the Lebesgue measure.

$|\cup I_j| = \sum |I_j| \leq |\cup (a_j , b_j)| \leq \sum (b_j - a_j) < \epsilon$ (the last inequlity is due to the choice of $(a_j ,b_j)$s)

Comment: I don't understand point 2. Why is $|x-a|<\delta$ for $x\in K$? In any case $x_j$ has the form $k_s\pm \delta_s$ and so is not necessarily an element of $K$.

Comment: @Alphie I edited my comment.

Comment: Why is $a\notin L$? Yes $x_j$ is of the form $k_s\pm \delta_s$ for some $s$ but how does this relate to the rest? I don't get your reasoning.

Comment: $P=\{a,b\}\cup\{x\in L : a< x <b\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ so $\{a,b\}\cap\{x\in L : a< x <b\} = \emptyset$.Hence $a\notin L$. The idea is that we can always find $\delta_{s'}$ such that $x_j > a+ \delta_{s'}$. $\delta_{s'}$ depends upon $k_{s'}$ (see (*)) which is chosen s.t $\delta_{s'}<\epsilon$.

Comment: In the proof $P$ is defined as $\{a,b\}\cup\{x\in L:a\leq x\leq b\}$. How do you find this $\delta_{s'}$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result by Lebesgue:

**Theorem:** A function $f$ is Riemann--integrable in $[a,b]$  iff
$f$ is bounded  and continuous $\lambda$--a.s. in $[a,b]$.

Necessity is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3742907/121671).

The proof of sufficiency relies on some technical results that  analyze the set where the integrand $f$ is continuous.

I present an online of these technical results below

---

Let $h$ be a function on an arbitrary space $X$
with values in a metric space $(S',d')$.
For any $T\subset S$,  the
modulus of continuity of $h$ on $T$ is defined as
$$\Omega_h(T):=\sup\{\rho'(h(x),h(y)):x,y\in T\}.$$
If $X$ is also a metric space,  the modulus of continuity $h$ at $x$ is
defined as
$$\omega_h(x)=\lim_{\delta\searrow0}\Omega_h(B(x;\delta))=\inf_{\delta>0}\Omega_h(B(x;\delta))$$

**Lemma 1:** Let $S$ and $S'$ be metric spaces and let $h:S\rightarrow S'$.
For any $r>0$, the set $J_r=\{x\in S:\omega_h(x)\geq r\}$ is closed.

Here is a short proof:

If $x\in J^c_r$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$\Omega_h(B(x;\delta))<r$. Clearly  $B(x;\delta)\subset J^c_r$.

**Lemma 2:**
For any function $h:S\longrightarrow S'$, the set $D_h\subset S$ of discontinuities of $h$ is a $\sigma$--F set and thus, Borel measurable.

Here is a short proof:

$h$ is continuous at $x$ if an only if
$\omega_h(x)=0$. By Lemma 1 the set  $J_\varepsilon=
\{x\in S:\omega(x)\geq\varepsilon\}$ is  closed in $S$. Therefore
$D_h=\bigcup_n J_{1/n}$ is a $\sigma$--F set.

**Lemma 3:**
If  $\omega_f(x)<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in[c,d]\subset[a,b]$, then exists $\delta>0$ such that $\Omega_f(T)<\epsilon$ for all $T\subset[c,d]$ with $\operatorname{diam}(T)<\delta$.

Here is a short proof:

For any $x\in[c,d]$ there is $\delta_x>0$ such that $\Omega_f(B(x;\delta_x)\cap[c,d])<\varepsilon$. The collection of all
$B(x;\delta_x/2)$ forms an open cover of $[c,d]$. By compactness, there are $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ with $[c,d]\subset\bigcup^k_{j=1}B(x_j;\delta_j/2)$. Let
$\delta=\min\{\delta_j/2\}$. If $T\subset[c,d]$ with
$\text{diam}(T)<\delta$, then  is fully contained in at least one
$B(x_j;\delta_j)$ so $\Omega_f(T)<\epsilon$.

---

Here is a proof of sufficiency of Lebesgue's theorem:

For each $r>0$, define
$J_r=\{x\in[a,b]:\omega_f(x)\geq r\}$. Each $J_r$ is a closed subset
in $[a,b]$  (see Lemma 1) and the set of discontinuities of $f$ is  given by $\mathcal{J}=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}J_{1/k}$. Each  $J_{1/k}$, being
a compact subset of measure zero, is covered by the union $A_k$ of
a finite collection of  open intervals in $[a,b]$ whose lengths add up to something less than $\tfrac1k$.  Clearly $B_k=[a,b]\setminus A_k$ is the union of a  finite collection of close subintervals in $[a,b]$.
By Lemma 3, there is $\delta_k>0$ such that if
$T\subset[a,b]\setminus A_k$ and $\text{diam}(T)<\delta_k$, then
$\Omega_f(T)<\tfrac1k$. Let $\mathcal{P}_k$ be a partition formed by
the subintervals of length less than $\delta_k$, and whose endpoints are with in $\mathcal{A}_k$ to in $B_k$. It follows that
$$
U(f,\mathcal{P}_k)-L(f,\mathcal{P}_k)=S_1+S_2
$$
where $S_1$ is formed by the subintervals containing points of $J_k$ and $S_2$ by subintervals contained in $B_k$. As $S_1\leq (M-m)/k$ and  $ S_2\leq (b-a)/k$, for $k$ large enough we have that $U(f,\mathcal{P}_k)-L(f,\mathcal{P}_k)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed proof. But can you help me understand the issues highlighted in the proof I posted ?